# Prove that if $F$ and $G$ are families of sets and $F \subseteq G$ then $\bigcup F \subseteq \bigcup G$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $\mathscr F$ and $\mathscr G$ are families of sets. Prove that if $\mathscr F \subseteq \mathscr G$ then $\bigcup \mathscr F \subseteq \bigcup \mathscr G$

My attempt:

Let $x \in \bigcup \mathscr F$. It follows that there is set $P$ such that $x \in P$ and $P \in \mathscr F$. Since $\mathscr F \subseteq \mathscr G$ we can conclude that $P \in \mathscr G$ and therefore $P\subseteq \bigcup \mathscr G$. Because $x \in P$, it follows that $x \in \bigcup \mathscr G$. Since x was arbitrary, we conclude that $\forall x ( x \in \mathscr \bigcup \mathscr P \implies x \in  \bigcup \mathscr G$). Hence $\bigcup \mathscr F \subseteq \bigcup \mathscr G$ $\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.